# Two Different Database Connections Same Time Python

Tags: python, sql, oracle

So I am currently looking to solve the following problem:

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
import pypyodbc
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user, password, name)
df = pd.read_sql(""" SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE DATE = '13JUN2018' """, connection)

connection_2 = pypyodbc.connect(blah, blah, db) 
df_2 = pd.read_sql(""" SELECT ID_2 FROM VW_TABLE WHERE DATE = '2018-06-13' """, connection_2)
```

I want to be able to compare these two results and determine what values are in df but not in df_2. Now I understand that this can be done by saying:

```
""" SELECT ID_2 FROM VW_TABLE WHERE DATE ='2018-06-13' AND ID_2 NOT IN ID"""
```

Where we pass ID as a list. I would prefer to do this all in one statement with an EXCEPT statement so I do not have to store df in memory.

Has anyone done anything like this where you are hitting two databases at once. I am partial to Python, but I am willing to look at other open source tools.

Comment: If you pull both data sets into Python, then you have to do the comparison in Python.  If you pull one data set into the other database, then you can do the comparison using SQL.  Depending on the complexity of the comparison(s), the latter approach might be preferable.

Comment: @rd_nielsen I am trying to only pull the result of ID_2 from VW_TABLE which is not in the list of ID from TABLE. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sure.  But if you pull the result of the Oracle query into SQLite as a new table, then you can reference it in a subquery, e.g. `where ID_2 not in (select ID from the_imported_table)`.

Comment: @rd_nielsen guess I am not super familiar with SQLite can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking that your second connection was to SQLite, but I see it's to some ODBC data source.  Nevertheless, the same approach would apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with lists. Get the first ID list:

```py
cur1 = connection.cursor()
cur2 = connection2.cursor()

cur1.execute("""SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE DATE = '13JUN2018' """)

List_ID = [ id[0] for ID in cur1.fetchall() ]

cur2.execute("""SELECT ID_2 FROM VW_TABLE WHERE DATE = '2018-06-13'""")

List_ID_2 = [ id[0] for ID in cur2.fetchall() ]

# This will subtract values of ID_2 list from ID List 
df1_not_2 = set(List_ID) - set(List_ID_2)
```